# Php api returns empty json array on PUT request

Tags: php, jquery

i am new to PHP so bare with me. So, i am trying to develop an online game (Score 4) with php, jquery and html. I created an API with php to represent different aspects of the game. For example, /board is a GET request that returns the board as it is stored in the database. My problem begins when i try to make a PUT request(create a new player), I get a 200 response from the server but the its just an empty JSON array. Here is the code. I dont know why its happening.

`

```
require_once "lib/dbconnect.php";
require_once "lib/board.php";
require_once "lib/game.php";
require_once "lib/users.php";


$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents( 'php://input' ),true);

switch($r=array_shift($request)){
    case 'board' :
        switch($b=array_shift($request)){
            case '' :
            case null : handle_board($method);
                break;
            case 'piece': handle_piece($method, $request);
                break;
            
            default: header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
                break;
        }
    break;
    
    case 'status':
        if(sizeof($request)==0)
        {show_status();}
        else {header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");}
        break;          
    case 'players' : handle_player($method, $request, $input);
            break;
    default: header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            exit;
    
}
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({url: "score4.php/players/"+p_color,
        method: 'PUT',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify( {username: $('#username').val(), player_color: p_color}),
        success: login_result,
        error: login_error});
```

I am getting empty json array instead of the data i try to pass through from my browswe

Comment: If you want to use switch inside of another switch, the case will need braces{} I would try checking out this question to see if that solves the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353240/php-switch-statement-inside-another-switch-statement

Comment: where are you retuning (echoing) the json ?
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);